# How do I use form_for with non-input elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ace-editor

I want to use [Ace Editor](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about) in my view for creating a post object, instead of a textarea, but Ace Editor requires the use of a `<div>` to contain its content. I'm new to Ruby on Rails 4 I'm trying to figure out how I can securely submit user input using the Ace Editor and redirect the user to the page that shows the post after it's been submitted. Here's my current form for submitting a post that does NOT yet use the Ace Editor `<div>`...

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
     <!-- I'd like to replace this text_area with the ace editor div-->
    <%= f.text_area :description %> 
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

How can I replace the f.text_area element with a `<div>` and include it's contents in the form's post request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new version of ace you can use textarea too

see http://jsbin.com/jodeyugenu/1/edit

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js"></script> 
  <style>
    #ta { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <div style="position:relative;height:200px;width:300px">
      <textarea id="ta">text</textarea> 
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" >
  </form>
</body>
<script>
  var textareaEl = document.getElementById("ta");
  // update textarea value before submitting
  var form = textareaEl.form
  form.addEventListener("submit", function() {    
    textareaEl.style.visibility = "hidden"
    textareaEl.value = editor.getValue()
    form.appendChild(textareaEl)
  });
  // create editor and set id for it
  editor = ace.edit(textareaEl)
  editor.container.id = "ta"
  // add a keyboard shortcut for submitting
  editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: "submit",
    exec: function() {
      form.submit()
    },
    bindKey: "Ctrl-Enter"
  })
</script>
</html>
```